# Full text search over SQL

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have sql table with the following columns:

```
item_id | title | description
```

I am going to implement full text search through description column. For example, search query for `asus notebook` should return all rows containing query. The number of rows can be very large (about 1 million). How effectively can I implement my search? What technologies do you recommend to use (Apache SOLR, etc...)? Can I use lucene? Any advice, any suggestions?

Comment: About Lucene: Lucene is an in-process library which has to be programmed upon. Do not try Lucene for PHP (if you find one) as the index is reloaded on every request. I don't know which language you use, but if you, for example, use the ASP.NET system you can share one Lucene instace in-process with all requests since the Lucene.NET implementation is thread-safe! If you use PHP or any other language which does not persist a state between requests, use SOLR which is a container for a Lucene instance accessible via RPC (over HTTP)

Comment: @sinni800 I'll second Lucene, it's pretty slick for searching. I've not had any issues with Lucene using the PHP Zend Framework.

Comment: In case You're building a PC parts store, I want to suggest forgetting the full-text, and simple searching in most common fiels, Category.Name, product.Name, Manufacturer.Name, Product.Code, ect.. 
I've done this in one of the shops, and is proven to be a sufficient solution.
Basically add a lot of where property like '%text%' and concatenate the conditions with OR.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using SQL, I would recommend PostgreSQL and its [full text search functionality](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch.html).

Comment: do you have any other suggestions beside SQL?

Comment: @torayeff If you really need a thousand searches per second, the recommendation should go more towards dedicated search systems like Apache Solr (which hosts a Apache Lucene instance for easy access through http). But first go the "easy" way using your basic SQL server, whichever you use. Only upgrade when your searches are getting too slow (saves work!)

Comment: @sinni800 Can you suggest me some tutorials?

Comment: @torayeff What web language do you use? For a general tutorial, see http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_1/doc-files/tutorial.html on the official SOLR site. For the PHP specific part check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php (I only guessed the language you use :) no hard feelings if it isn't PHP!) But I can't stress enough that unless you will need LOTS of requests (100s to 1000s per second) the built in full text search of such SQL servers as MySQL or the suggested PostgreSQL WILL suffice!

Comment: @sinni800 - That really depends on the amount of data to search through. I just watched a [webinar](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/08/24/full-text-search-webinar-questions/) (admittedly on mysql) but even in the best scenario (MyISAM) on the stackoverflow 8BG datadump solr was at 10-100 times faster than the provided fulltext search

Comment: @Nifle that MyISAM is the best scenario isn't even correct sometimes. I know somebody who hosts a large database (roughly 2,680,000 entries in one table only) which is FTS-indexed. MyISAM is SLOWER on this database even when doing ONLY read requests. But that's not the goal in this - afaik SOLR gives you the best advantage when the number of searches increase, but not so much if only the amount of data searched increases... It was the case with my friends 2.6 million entry table.